# Cached DataSet Table Rows Disappear After first use

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I'm Caching a very Costly Query to populate 4 different DropDown Boxes in one of our Class files. I have spent way too much time trying everything I know to get this to work with no luck. The first time through, the DataSet gets cached and everything looks good. If I refresh the page, the code passes the null check of the cached item, but there are no rows in the cached DataSet and the dropdowns don't get populated.

As far as I know, I'm doing this like all the examples on MSDN and other sites. I just can't get the cache to stick. The DataSet only has 140 rows, so it's not getting kicked out for size. I have tried to set it to never expire with no luck as well. If anyone could help me, I'd geatly appreciate it.

I have checked the App Pool settings and they seem to give plenty of time before recycling. The wierd thing about this is when the DataSet is cached the first time through, the data is there. When I refresh the page, the DataSet column Headers are in the cached item, but no Data, so it is passing the null check. I'm really scratching my head on this one. I am able to Cache a string, but for some reason, not the DataSet for longer than one request. From setting a watch on the Cached item, it hangs around until the method is called for the second time and when the method kicks off, it empties the DataSet.

I added the delegate CacheItemRemovedCallback and couldn't get it to trigger unless I deleted the cache item manually. The cached object remains in cache, it's the DataSet rows that are disappearing. If you open up the cached DataSet, it has the column names, with no rows. Because of this, it is passing the

```
if(cacheItem == null)
```

check. I can cache a string with no issues, it remains in cache until it expires or I remove it manually. I'm really at a loss. Is there any other way for me to try and cache the item? I don't think session would work, the query is just too costly to the system to use it at the session level.

```
public DataSet ReturnPhysicianSpecialtyCodes() 
{ 
    string cacheKey = "PhysCodes"; 
    object cacheItem = HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheKey] as DataSet; 
    if(cacheItem == null) 
    { 
        string sqlCommand = 
            "SELECT DISTINCT SPECIALTY_CODE, SPECIALTY " + 
            "FROM   PHARM.PHYSICIAN_SPECIALTY " +
            "ORDER BY SPECIALTY"; 

        cacheItem = OracleHelper.ExecuteDataset(
            this.Connection, 
            CommandType.Text,     
            sqlCommand); 

        HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert( 
            cacheKey, 
            cacheItem, 
            null, 
            Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, 
            new TimeSpan(1, 
            0, 0), 
            CacheItemPriority.Default, null); 
        } 
        return (DataSet)cacheItem;            
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for everyones help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using some other container, like List. Populate it using cmd.ExecuteDatareader and store in cache. Works like a charm. Using datasets is a bad practice if you only need to bind dropdowns.

Comment: I was thinking an XML representation of the dataset and storing that in Cache. Could you povide a small snippit of how I wwould accomplish it with my current code?

Answer (score 0):

I usually do my caching like this...

```
public DataSet ReturnPhysicianSpecialtyCodes() {
    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
    string cacheKey = "PhysCodes";
    DataSet cacheItem = (DataSet)context.Cache.Get(cacheKey);
    if(cacheItem == null) {
        string sqlCommand =
            "SELECT DISTINCT SPECIALTY_CODE, SPECIALTY " +
            "FROM PHARM.PHYSICIAN_SPECIALTY " +
            "ORDER BY SPECIALTY";
        cacheItem = OracleHelper.ExecuteDataset(
            this.Connection,
            CommandType.Text,
            sqlCommand);
        context.Cache.Add(
            cacheKey,
            cacheItem,
            null,
            Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration,
            Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
            CacheItemPriority.Normal,
            null);
    }
    return (DataSet)cacheItem;
}
```

Not that there is a lot of difference between this and what you are doing, but this works for me.

Comment: Hi Kevin, Thank you for your example, I dropped into the site and ran it with the same results. From all of the different ways that people have suggested that I try, I have been getting the same results. I'm really beginning to think that the code is fine and that it's something to do with IIS or something like that. I don't have a lot of experience with caching and IIS settings.